# How to get available modules with pythonnet

Tags: python, .net, python-3.x, python.net

I'm trying to import a .net dll into python and would like to figure out how to see what modules are available.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
from System.Windows.Forms import Form
```

After the clr.AddReference line how can I see what is available to import? I would like to know that  System.Windows.Forms is available and that Form is available.

I have an internal .net dll I am trying to work with, and couldn't figure out how to see what the modules I needed to call without an example. Once I got this point, I can see what's available with something like

```
form = Form()
print(dir(form))
```

I was able to get the info I needed with the following code:

```
dll_ref = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(full_path)
print(dll_ref.FullName)
print(dll_ref.Location)
for i in range(len(dll_ref.DefinedTypes)):
    print(dll_ref.DefinedTypes[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tools that can show you members in .NET DLL. One is Object Explorer in Visual Studio. There is also a free tool from JetBrains called dotPeek.

If you want to do it from Python, you need to either  `dir` on a namespace that you must know in advance, or use .NET reflection to inspect the DLL programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried the code below and I got what I needed.

dll_ref = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(full_path)

print(dll_ref.FullName)

print(dll_ref.Location)

for i in range(len(dll_ref.DefinedTypes)):

    print(dll_ref.DefinedTypes[i])

Comment: How about using `list(clr.ListAssemblies(False))` and `clr._available_namespaces`? Is this what you intended?